# Conveying "Go bust"

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques

The idiom "go bust" (informal) means to spend or lose all of one's money; to go broke. If a company *goes bust*, it goes bankrupt. Linguee gives *faire faillite* as translation but it sounds to me a little formal. Can "couler la baraque convey the meaning of the English idiom? E.g.

> He lost his job when the company went bust.

> Il a perdu son boulot lorsque l'entreprise a coulé la baraque.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Il a perdu son boulot quand sa boite a **mis la clef sous la porte**.

Answer (score 2):

> Il a perdu son boulot quand sa boîte a coulé.

convient très bien. Ajouter *la baraque* ne convient pas, puisque c'est redondant avec *sa boîte*